# Python variable scope in dynamic functions

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

I recently implemented a function factory that didn't scope a variable the way I expected.

I found a solution, but I don't know why it works.

So although I don't strictly need a solution to this problem, I've posted this question in the hope of learning something about variable scope.

**Problematic Code**

```
# Create function list
func_list = []
for i in [1, 2]:
    def _func():
        print("%i" % i)
    func_list.append(_func)

# Execute
for f in func_list:
    f()
```

Gives the same ouptut; always the last loop element:

```
2
2
```

**Solution**

```
# Create function list
def make_func(i):
    def _func():
        print("%i" % i)

    return _func

func_list = []
for i in [1, 2]:
    func_list.append(make_func(i))

# Execute
for f in func_list:
    f()
```

Gives what I expected all along:

```
1
2
```

**Why?** so my questions are:

- Why doesn't the first method work?
- How is the working implementation functionally different to the first?

Comment: I guess return function returns the value of it rather than the reference. Hence the second code works out. Though I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is called a "closure".

In the first example, `i` is changed, and the created function returns it. The function doesn't record the value and return it when called. It just returns the current value of `i`, which has already changed.

In the second example, you define a new `i` every time you call the outer function and its value is never changed.